# MAAS 2.0 Update bonding driver configuration

Tags: maas

Is there a better way to do it than this? All I could find to update the bonding parameters was to use the DB as below. I can't find it in the GUI nor a way to do it via CLI.

```
sudo maas-region dbshell --installed

psql (9.5.5)
Type "help" for help.

maasdb=# select * from maasserver_interface where type = 'bond';
maasdb=# select * from maasserver_interface where type = 'bond';
maasdb=# update maasserver_interface set params = '{"bond_downdelay": 0,     "bond_lacp_rate": "slow", "bond_miimon": 100, "bond_mode": "balance-rr", "bond_updelay": 0, "bond_xmit_hash_policy": "layer2"}' where type = 'bond';
UPDATE 15
maasdb=# select * from maasserver_interface where type = 'bond';

maasdb=# \q`
```

Comment: you can ask it on maas IRC channel where you can get some quick responses, channel: #maas

Comment: Thanks, The IRC was able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: welcome @Don :)

Answer (score 1):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1645319

This is available in MAAS 2.1. The documentation is off but it is available.